# AWS Auto scaling EC2 Windows base on user login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I want to move the windows workspace to AWS. So I create multiple EC2 (Windows) and Remote to it for use. Because number of user is flexible to use EC2 so I used auto-scale behind NLB (Network Load Balance) to control it.
But I want to set up Auto scaling automation and add new EC2 if the current EC2 is full. How can I do that?

Comment: Will these EC2 instances be used by connecting via Remote Desktop? If so, what is the purpose of the Load Balancer? Or are the EC2 instances being used as web servers? Also, what do you mean by "if the current EC2 is full" -- how do you determine if an instance is "full"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
"what is the purpose of the Load Balancer" => Because auto scaling, user just need ALB domain.
" what do you mean by "if the current EC2 is full" => Assum I setting min 2 EC2: User A remote to EC2 1, User B remote to EC2 2. And auto scale will automation to add new EC2 to prepare new user.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your purpose for running the Amazon EC2 instances is to allow users to connect via Remote Desktop, which uses the RDP protocol.

If so, it is **not appropriate to use a Load Balancer**. A Load Balancer can only route web traffic. It cannot route RDP traffic. Plus, you do not want to 'load balance' RDP traffic because you will want a particular user to always go back to the same instance, rather than being 'load balanced' between multiple instances.

Amazon EC2 **Auto Scaling is *not* appropriate** for your use-case. For example, if multiple instances were in use but there was only one user per instance, Auto Scaling would scale-in by terminating instances. This would kill the session that is currently being used on those instances. This is not a good user experience.

A more appropriate service would be [Amazon WorkSpaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces.html):

> Amazon WorkSpaces enables you to provision virtual, cloud-based Microsoft Windows, Amazon Linux, or Ubuntu Linux desktops for your users, known as WorkSpaces. WorkSpaces eliminates the need to procure and deploy hardware or install complex software. You can quickly add or remove users as your needs change. Users can access their virtual desktops from multiple devices or web browsers.

[Amazon WorkSpaces Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/pricing/) offers monthly subscriptions (good for people who require a WorkSpace throughout the month), or hourly pricing (good for occasional users).